# Why is CTE performing extremelly better than temporary tables in Sql Data Warehouse?

Tags: azure-synapse

I want to select data from a big table (around 1 bilion rows) that matches the id with a table created from json incoming data.

Here is what I did first:

```
SELECT * 
#JsonIds 
FROM OPENJSON(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), '[{"id": "18897126"},{"id": "710990568"},{"id": "610990568"},{"id": "510990568"}]')) 
WITH (id BIGINT); 

SELECT * 
FROM #jsonIds j 
INNER JOIN [schema].[myBigTable] t ON t.id = j.id
```

This performed terribly. It took almost 3 minutes to finish!

After a few tries, I have decided to see how CTE would perform:

```
WITH JsonIds AS 
( 
    SELECT *     
    FROM OPENJSON(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), '[{"id": "18897126"},{"id": "710990568"},{"id": "610990568"},{"id": "510990568"}]')) 
    WITH (id BIGINT) 
)  
SELECT p.* 
FROM [schema].[myBigTable] p 
inner join JsonIds j on p.id = j.id
```

For my surprise, the CTE went much better. It took less than a second.

Why is CTE performing so much better on such a simple query like this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a statistic to the temp table:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #JsonIds 
FROM OPENJSON(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), '[{"id": "18897126"},{"id": "710990568"},{"id": "610990568"},{"id": "510990568"}]')) 
WITH (id BIGINT); 

CREATE STATISTICS StatId on #JsonIds (id);

SELECT * 
FROM #jsonIds j 
INNER JOIN [schema].[myBigTable] t ON t.id = j.id
```

Auto-create stats doesn’t happen on temp tables. So Azure DW is probably making bad assumptions about the content of the temp table.

If the above doesn’t help then try putting the word `EXPLAIN` before each statement and including the resulting XML explain plan in the question so we can see what it’s doing.